# Wordpress/PHP - Show form submissions on page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I need to make website where users will enter some simple information like Name, email, and phone model, and after they click submit that info should show on that same page.

Can someone help me out to figure out what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Too broad, you will need to hire a wordpress programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$name = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$email = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$model = isset( $_POST['model'] ) ? $_POST['model'] : '';
?>
<form action="./signup" method="POST">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
    <label>Phone Model:</label>
    <input type="text" name="model" value="<?php echo $model; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```